# Passing object in function params

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain me this?
In first code I only have one `params` in login function and it works when I pass an object, but in the second one there is `email, password` and I pass here an object aswell. So do I need to add two params or one if Im passing an object, because they both work..?

```js
login(params) {
    return axios.post(`/auth/login`, params);
  },
```

```js
    doLogin({ state }) {
      return api.auth
        .login({
          email: state.email,
          password: state.password,
        });
    }
```

Another code

```js
login(login, password) {
    return axios.post(`/auth/login`, {
    login,
    password
});

  },
```

```js
    doLogin({ state }) {
      return api.auth
        .login({
          email: state.email,
          password: state.password,
        });
    }
```

Comment: The login in the second code is going to be {login, password} an object.

Comment: Let me explain more, in the second code what you're doing is accepting 2 parameters i.e. login and password. But you're passing only an object i.e. {email: state.email, password: state.password}, so the login parameter is going to be { email: state.email, password: state.password } in the login method.

Answer (score 0):

In the second one you have to pass 2 params corresponding to 2 properties of the object. If you pass an object to this `login` function, it will understand `login = { email: state.email, password: state.password }` and `password = undefined`.
Like this:

```
    doLogin({ state }) {
      return api.auth
        .login({
          email: state.email,
          password: state.password,
        },
        undefined
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood is you need to know which is better method (correct me if I am wrong).

the lesser the parameters the better the function in my opinion...

So use first method as you are directly passing the object and there is no need to hard code an object from the arguments.

And in second method you have same function name (login) and parameter name which is confusing (change the parameter to 'email')

In second method it's bit tedious to maintain the code.